# Reading a Dictionary inside JSON

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my JSON

```
[{"dict": {"key": "value1"}}, {"dict": {"key": "value2"}}]
```

Here is my parse code:

```
val mdf = sparkSession.read.option("multiLine","true").json("multi2.json")
mdf.show(false)
```

This outputs:

```
+--------+
|dict    |
+--------+
|[value1]|
|[value2]|
+--------+
```

I want to see the name-value pairs? The keys and the values.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I answered below :) see if that helps. I deleted it because somebody just downvoted without a reason. :(

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Not by me.  Can you post again please?

Comment: I will get downvoted again :( Did you test it? Did it work?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I can't see it

Comment: I have enabled it but its downvoted

Answer (score 6):

If you want to expand data just `select dict.*` (note that the option is named `multiline` not `multiLine`):

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("multi2.json")
df.select($"dict.*").show

// +------+
// |   key|
// +------+
// |value1|
// |value2|
// +------+
```

If you want to treat it as a dictionary just provide the schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("dict", MapType(StringType, StringType))
))

val dfm = spark.read
  .schema(schema)
  .option("multiline", "true")
  .json("multi2.json")

dfm.show
// +------------------+
// |              dict|
// +------------------+
// |Map(key -> value1)|
// |Map(key -> value2)|
// +------------------+
```

and if you want a pair per row, just explode the result:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

dfm.select(explode(col("dict"))).show
// +---+------+
// |key| value|
// +---+------+
// |key|value1|
// |key|value2|
// +---+------+
```

Comment: The input is just one line. Not clear why multiline needs set at all

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways is

```
val mdf = sqlContext.read.option("multiLine","true").json("multi2.json")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
mdf.withColumn("dict", split(regexp_replace(to_json(col("dict")), "[}{\"]", ""), ","))
    .withColumn("dict", explode(col("dict")))
    .withColumn("dict", split(col("dict"), ":"))
    .select(col("dict")(0).as("key"), col("dict")(1).as("value"))
  .show(false)
```

Which should give you

```
+---+------+
|key|value |
+---+------+
|key|value1|
|key|value2|
+---+------+
```

It should work for **jsons with multiple key values** as

```
[ {"dict": {"key": "value1", "key2": "vvv"}}, {"dict": {"key": "value2", "key3": "v332"}} ]
```

above code should give you

```
+----+------+
|key |value |
+----+------+
|key |value1|
|key2|vvv   |
|key |value2|
|key3|v332  |
+----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks.  It works but code is very complex. All those withColumns(),  Ill leave open to see if there is another way

Comment: @cricket_007 I used regex_replace to remove the unnecessary characters from strings

Comment: Where exactly are the unnecessary characters? It's a valid JSON array, which Spark can read fine...

Comment: when i used to_json, the json is converted to string and { and } and " are present in that string. So I used regex_replace to replace them with empty @cricket_007

Comment: Sure... But as shown in the other answer. That's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yes I saw that . I didn't know we can use map schema like that when I answered this. Thats why I upvoted the other answer. I was going to suggest using udf function but that would be useless too compared to the other answer @cricket_007

Comment: Unnecessary is one thing. But it will break on any not naive data. Try `[{"dict": {"key": "\"value\":1"}}, {"dict": {"key": "{value2}"}}]`